# Drawing the following diagram

Tags: diagrams

I hope to draw the following diagram

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If you look at the `tikz-cd` manual you will find it straightforward to draw this.

Comment: I hope that you can help me because I'm biginner in Latex

Comment: Can you please edit the title of your question to reflect what your question is about? In it's current state, it will help no future user who might have the same problem simply because nobody will be able to search for it.

Comment: @samcarter I hope that you suggest me a title because my goal is to draw this diagram which is related to a mathematical problem.

Comment: @Schüler I have no idea what your diagram shows, so I'm not a good source of title suggestions -- but you must surly know what your question is about?

Comment: Of course the goal of my question is to draw the above diagram because I want to add it in my presentation.

Comment: I guess samcarter was suggesting to make the title more relevant. For example "How do I draw commutative diagrams" or even better if this is a special kind of diagram with a name: "How do I draw Hallmackenreuther diagrams". In its current form the title may be correct, but not really helpful for other people with a similar problem. Of course you could also include a more detailed description in the question body.

Comment: Everybody is forgetting the tilde in the answers below... lol of course it does not matter... :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of this site is to help you when you got stuck trying something, not to convert screen shots into LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\mathcal{H} \arrow[d,"W_A" swap] \arrow[r,"T"]& \mathcal{H} \arrow[d,"W_A"] \\
\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2}) \arrow[r,"T" swap] & \mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when I compile it looks a little small. Can I enlarge it a bit? Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: @Schüler Sure, as explained e.g. [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270285/121799) you may just replace `\begin{tikzcd}`by  e.g. `\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]`.

Answer (score 5):

Similar output of the great user @marmot using an alternative `xy` package from this guide [`XY-pic`](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cautis/tools/xypic.pdf).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
\mathcal{H} \ar[d]_{W_A} \ar[r]^T
& \mathcal{H} \ar[d]^{W_A}\\
\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2}) \ar[r]^{\tilde T} & \mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why you started your diagram with empty col (by `&`)?

Comment: Also, `mathtools` is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: You need only `{ ... & ... \\ ... & ...}`

Comment: @Sigur I have edited all. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Obligatory `tikzcd` editor answer: https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/

Click the screenshot to open in the editor.

[image]

Generated code by clicking the `{}` button (not an MWE):

```
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathcal{H} \arrow[rr, "T"] \arrow[d, "W_A"'] &  & \mathcal{H} \arrow[d, "W_A"] \\
\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2}) \arrow[rr, "\tilde{T}"] &  & \mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})
\end{tikzcd}
```