# How to draw the commutative diagram of binary products in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I am trying to draw the commutative graph below in LaTeX. I have looked up and know the most effective way to do this is to load `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` but I can't figure how to write the code. I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this just an adaptation of the example at the top if page 3 in the `tikz-cd` manual. Especially the `bend left` etc

Comment: Yeah, I have looked at that I am struggling to get the arrows x and y used in the example in the manual to go to different objects.

Comment: Note that you are more likely to get help if you provide the code you have so far (as a full but minimal example that others can try as is)

Comment: @Elise please see the answer below  - I have not done the labeling -- hope you can complete that part

Comment: @Elise would you like to accept the answer and /or upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        &   A   \arrow[d,red,]
                \arrow[dl, bend right]
                \arrow[dr, bend left]               &   \\
    X   &   P   \arrow[r, green]\arrow[l, green]    &   Y
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**edit for label**

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        &   A   \arrow[d,red,]
                \arrow[dl, bend right]
                \arrow[dr, bend left]               &   \\
    X   &   P   \arrow[r, green, "x1"']\arrow[l, green, "x2"]   &   Y
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**edit for scaling**

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \adjustbox{scale=4, center}{
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
        &   A   \arrow[d,red,]
                \arrow[dl, bend right]
                \arrow[dr, bend left]               &   \\
    X   &   P   \arrow[r, green, "x1"']\arrow[l, green, "x2"]   &   Y
    \end{tikzcd}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hiya, Thank you for all your help. I was able to label the graph. I just have 2 questions if you don't mind answering them. Is there a command to get the labels on the axis on the same side of the arrow. For example when I labelled the x_1 and x_2 arrows I got one above the arrow and one below the arrow. I used the command "x_1" to label them. Secondly, is there any command I can use to make the diagram bigger? Thank you.

Comment: @Elise please see the edit  above

Comment: for the scaling part you can refer here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270285/197451

Comment: Got it, once again thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Elise using adjustbox to scale as defined here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325309/197451